this css {overflow-x:hidden;} not working for me?
I have a site page https://www.chattanoogamusicscene.com/locations-2/ but Im having overflow issues on mobile view. I am missing or just not understanding something. I have tried several css from but these are not working for example
 html {
   ...
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

 body {
   ...
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

this only cuts of the view and removes the scrolling
